# How to fetch campaign by name using facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

How can I fetch the facebook campaign by name, I am able to fetch campaign by id

> APIContext context = new APIContext(ACCESS_TOKEN, APP_SECRET);
>   Campaign campaign = Campaign.fetchById(CAMPAIGN_ID, context);

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. The API requests are by ID.

However, you could pull a list of all campaigns (ids + names) associated with an account and use that to fetch a campaign by its name. ([Documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/))

Once you have the name, you'll have the ID and then can make the API request.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API, where you can find campaign by Name. I am using it and it's working fine.

```
AdAccount account = new AdAccount(adAccountId, getContext());
StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
params.append("[{ \"field\":\"name\",\"value\":\"{Your campaign Name}\",\"operator\":\"EQUAL\"}]");     
APINodeList<Campaign> campaignsList = account.getCampaigns().setParam("filtering", params.toString()).requestNameField().execute();
```